# Remove Style if CSS3 Support

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove a style in the case that browser specific CSS 3 items (drop shadows, rounded corners, etc.)? For example:

```
.fancy
{
  /* only display if no drop shadow support */
  border: thin solid #888;

  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS doesn't do conditionals. In any version.

What you can do is dynamically serve up different stylesheets for browsers that support CSS3.

Comment: CSS doesn't, but there are some languages that compile to CSS--such as Less (lesscss.org) and Sass (sass-lang.com)--I doubt either will solve *this* problem, but they are an interesting approach to shoring up some CSS shortcomings.

Answer (score 3):

It's better if you don't remove style rules, but only apply them when CSS3 is enabled. You could use this fancy piece of Javascript for it, called **[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)**.

Let me give you a quick example of how you could use it in your stylesheet:

```
.boxshadow .fancy {
    border: thin solid #888;

    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
}
```

Modernizr adds classes to the HTML element, which tells you what browser functionalities are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Since CSS3 is style-markup, and not a programming language, you can't do true "if-else"--however you could design your CSS3 styles to override the CSS2 styles, and the end result would be CSS3 where supported with CSS2 as a fallback.

In terms of practicality however, this approach will likely be more painful than dynamically serving CSS3 stylesheets to supported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

One means -though given the patchy nature of css adoption/implementation it might/will not work exhaustively- is to use:

```
.fancy
{
  border: thin solid #888;
}

.fancy:nth-of-type(odd), .fancy:nth-of-type(even)
{
   border: 0 none transparent;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #888;
}
```

This is a bit messy in that the selector has to explicitly target all the `odd` and `even` `.fancy` elements, I'd prefer a neater solution but it does work (certainly in Chrome/Linux). Demo at: http://jsbin.com/ezako3